# Decrypting Sitecore IP binary data coming from mongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb, sitecore

We have application where sitecore analytics data is getting logged into mongoDB.

i have written java process to fetch this analytics data from mongo collections. Some of the collection has IP address value which is getting as below,

Ip":{"$binary":"rBBvbQ==","$type":"00"}

i want, the original IP values to be return based on the $type value. Please suggest how i can get this.

Comment: What about the application writing the data? Is it doing **"it's"** job correctly or not? It depends on your point of view. The data stored is in "binary" format, and that's a result of what something sent it to MongoDB as ( likely a struct of the octets ). So either you read it back and translate the same way, or you fix the process to make the data readable and queryable. So it sounds more like the "writer" is at fault, and no matter which way you go, that code also has the answer to the written format. So what is the code there?

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB operates with Javascript language. You can load your script with next syntax:

```
load("scripts/ip-address-globals.js")
```

This script file can contains next code:

```
Address4.fromHex = function (hex) {
  var padded = padStart(hex.replace(/:/g, ''), 8, '0');
  var groups = [];
  var i;

  for (i = 0; i < 8; i += 2) {
    var h = padded.slice(i, i + 2);

    groups.push(parseInt(h, 16));
  }

  return new Address4(groups.join('.'));
};
```

You can call this function to get address in normal format.

P.S. this function was taken from [ip-address](https://github.com/beaugunderson/ip-address) library on GitHub. It worth to take a look on it and probably use full library, rather than get only function that you need.